# Laravel query with date range and orWhere returns wrong results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

need help in formulating eloquent query, I have this query which uses orWhere however I can't get the correct results when I wanted to added date range in the query.

`comment table`

| id | content | user_id | post_id | created_at | is_owner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | 1 | 1 | 2022-07-09T04:28:50 | false |
| 2 | test 1 | 2 | 2 | 2022-07-10T04:28:50 | true |
| 3 | test 2 | 2 | 3 | 2022-07-11T04:28:50 | true |
| 4 | test 3 | 2 | 2 | 2022-07-11T04:28:50 | false |
| 5 | test 4 | 3 | 3 | 2022-07-12T04:28:50 | true |
| 6 | test 5 | 2 | 2 | 2022-07-14T04:28:50 | false |
| 7 | test 6 | 4 | 2 | 2022-07-14T04:28:50 | false |
| 8 | test 7 | 5 | 1 | 2022-07-15T04:28:50 | false |

Assuming I have the table above with it's data and the login user is the owner of the comment.

Code

```
$comment = Comment::where(function ($query) use ($postIds, $userId) {
        $query->whereIn('post_id', $postIds)
            ->where('user_id', $userId);
    }
)

if ($isCommentOwner) {
    $comment->orWhere(function ($query) {
         ->where('is_owner', true);
    }); 
}
```

Using the code above I got the corrects results however when I tried to filter it out by date I can't get correct results.

The code above generate below query.

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
  `comments`
WHERE
(
    (
        `post_id` in (1, 2)
        AND `user_id` = 2
    )
     OR (`is_owner` = 1)
)
AND `document_issues`.`deleted_at` IS NULL  
ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
```

I wanted to filter the comment created from the given date range, I tried adding the ff. code.

```
$comment->whereDate('created_at', '>=', '2022-07-13')
$comment->whereDate('created_at', '<=', '2022-07-15');
```

However, I can't get the correct filtered results.

Filtering with date do work when I remove `orWhere`

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `Carbon` instances of dates? eg. `$begin = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2022-07-13')`

Comment: Yes, tried it still the same

Answer (score 0):

I missed an important thing. You need to provide an array to whereDate method:

```php
// whereDate need a query as first parameter
// i think the method is usually used in closures.
$comment->whereDate($comment, ['created_at', '>=', '2022-07-13'])
$comment->whereDate($comment, ['created_at', '<=', '2022-07-15']);
```

Comment: Tried this but I got syntax error.

`Too few arguments to function Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::whereDate(), 1 passed in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php`

Comment: I improved the answer. The answer from @halim can be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

use **whereBetween** try this query

```
    $from ="2022-07-09";
    $to = "2022-07-12";
    $postIds = [1,2];
    $comment = Comment::where(function ($query) use ($postIds, $userId,$from, $to) {
        $query->whereIn('post_id', $postIds)
            ->where('user_id', $userId)
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to]);
    }
    )->get();

  if ($isCommentOwner) {
     $comment = $comment->filter(function ($item){
          return $item->is_owner == true;
        });
   }
```

Comment: Still the same, however filter with date is working when I remove `orWhere`

Comment: explain to me what you need to do exactly , I excute this query and work fine with me @blitzen12

Comment: The query works however when you add the code below it's not working anymore.

`$comment->orWhere(function ($query) {
         ->where('is_owner', true);
    }); `

Comment: try this :   if ($isCommentOwner) {
$comment = $comment->filter(function ($item){
              return $item->is_owner == true;
            });
} @blitzen12

Comment: actually this is my last option however what I'm worried about is that will it affect performance in the future?